# How to start LaunchPad service of SQL Server on Ubuntu?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, python

I'm running SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04.

When trying to run an external Python script, I got the following error:

```
Msg 39011, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
SQL Server was unable to communicate with the LaunchPad service. Please verify the configuration of the service.
```

I searched and found out that the solution on Windows is to start the service of LaunchPad with Windows' service manager.

But I need the equivalent of Ubuntu. I don't even know what the LaunchPad service is called.

Comment: You want to run SQL Server in Ubuntu or you are trying to run Python Script in Ubuntu. Both things are different.

Comment: I want to run SQL server on Ubuntu and I have no problem of doing that. And I want that SQL server to run Python.

Answer (score 2):

[Linux Support Roadmap for SQL Server Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/what-s-new-in-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-2017#linux-support-roadmap):

"Machine learning using R or Python in-database is not currently supported in SQL Server on Linux. Look for announcements in a later release.

However, on Linux you can perform native scoring using the T-SQL PREDICT function. Native scoring lets you score from a pretrained model very fast, without calling or even requiring an R runtime. This means you can use SQL Server on Linux to generate predictions very fast, to serve client applications."

The stand-alone [Machine Learning Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/machinelearningserver) is already supported on Linux.